# Selecting FTP protocol in WinSCP script

Tags: batch-file, ftp, sftp, winscp

Before scheduling script it is worth to check how it works. so from `Command Prompt` I have just run my batch file.

> The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP
>   connections. Did you want to use FTP protocol instead of SFTP? Prefer
>   using encryption.

Image:
[image: My login window on WinSCP: Selected FTP protocol explicitly]

As shown in the image above, I have specified that It is FTP file protocol. But It doesn't help.

So far I have looked up:

- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_server_rejected_sftp_listens_for_ftp
- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login

And It works fine on FileZilla as FTP. Therefore, I can eliminate the following possibilities:

- Server unexpectedly closed network connection;
- Network error: Connection refused;
- Network error: Connection reset by peer;
- Network error: Connection timed out.

And here is my `.bat` for reference:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\winSCP\winSCP.com" /script="C:\test\Test.txt
```

And `.txt`:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ***.**.**.**
lcd C:\Transfer\ToABCTest\
get -delete  /test_edi_in/*.txt
close
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the FTP protocol in the script using the `ftp://` scheme in the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url):

```
open ftp://***.**.**.**
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!! Hope you have awesome holidays! :)